# What is the closest equivalent in Nuxt 3 to an "Anonymous Middleware" from Nuxt 2?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am learning about [Nuxt 3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) at the moment and currently focus on things that I knew how to handle in Nuxt 2 and for which I did not yet find a (similar, simple) solution in Nuxt 3.

One of those things are [**anonymous middlewares**](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/middlewares/anonymous/).
How can I build those in Nuxt 3 / what is the closest thing in Nuxt 3 that can be used to get the same functionallity?
Do I really have to call an API endpoint?
This seems so overkill compared to Nuxt 2.

Comment: Hey, I'm keeping the tag with `nuxtjs3` only to have a single source and not split the community around several tags (pretty much like for Vue3). I'll give it a better abstract I guess, so that it looks more "interesting".

Comment: @kissu Both tags are currently very small, why not merging them? One could also mention this on meta to get help.

Comment: Yeah, we need to do that, but it requires 5 points in the tag itself to submit a synonym. Also, sharing it on Meta could be a really good idea indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [discussion](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/906) may be helpful to track the status of the question.
The latest and most useful place where you can get the up-to date info [is here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2082).

TLDR: no client-side middleware as of today but you can have workarounds.